# Persistent variables in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
def edit
    @title ="Edit account"
    @page_name = "edit"    
  end

  def update
    if @wsp.update_attributes(params[:wsp])
      # it worked
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      if (@title == "Location")
        redirect_to wsp_location_path
      else
        redirect_to edit_wsp_path
      end
    else 
      @title = "Edit account"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

The variable @title is empty when in the update method. How can I make the @title persistent so I can read it?

Comment: I am assuming that these are controller actions? You need to be more clear about the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each controller action is executed in a separate request, so you are losing the values in between.

You probably need to use `session`, or better yet `flash` to store the title across requests.

```
def edit
  flash[:title] = @title = "Edit account"
  ...
end

def update
  ...
  if (flash[:title] == "Location")
    redirect_to wsp_location_path
  else
    redirect_to edit_wsp_path
  end
end
```

Comment: the code works but the message "Location" and "Edit account" is always showing on the screen. I've tried flash.now but it's still there. How do I remove it?

Comment: @donald How are you using flash in your views? It shouldn't show up unless you add it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

In the `edit` action, you should write the result to a form field, perhaps a hidden field.  Then read that data back in from the submitted form in your `update` action.  You really should not preserve any state server side between these 2 requests.

And while you could use the session, I would advise against this.  Overuse of the session for passing tiny bits of short lived data between requests is generally bad form.

Comment: Passing short-lived bits of data between requests is the entire purpose of `flash`. Using a hidden field may be a bad idea if you don't want users to have the ability to alter the behavior.

Comment: @Adam, I suppose you are right.  But that doesn't really seem to be the case in this example.  `flash` wouldn't be horrible, but `session` would.

Answer (score 0):

If the entire purpose of this is to display it on the Edit page, why not put it there (`app/views/the_controller/edit.html.erb`)? That way it'd be shown on all requests to that page and you're not putting view / presentation code into the controller where it doesn't belong.